# Listing everything as technical skills

Tags: resume, software-industry, career-development

I really can't find a place to research this, and I'd like some professional input.

How commonly do you see such organization on a CV:

**Technical Skills:**

*Java, JavaScript, .Net, XML, J2EE, HTML, TCP/IP, REST, SOAP, SOA, Visual Studio .Net, Eclipse, SQL, MS SQL Server, MySQL, JUnit, jQuery, C, C++, Tomcat, Spring Framework, Hibernate, Maven, JDeveloper, WebLogic, IIS, Google Web Toolkit and more*

Basically you have only a single section with "technical skills" where you dump all the stuff.

Would you be surprised if someone had this on CV? To me this seems alright.

Is this accepted in industry?

Comment: Perhaps you should narrow it down to skills related to what you're applying to then list the remaining skills under "other."

Answer (score 6):

To me this looks like an unorganized laundry list of everything you have ever touched. But it doesn't tell me anything about how well you know any of these technologies. Your level of proficiency could be anywhere between knowing them inside out and having heard they exist. It would also help if you would make some logical grouping for better readability. Example:

> X years of experience with Java (using technologies like J2EE on Tomcat, JUnit, Spring Framework, Hibernate and IDEs JDeveloper and Eclipse) and various database technologies (MSSQL Server, MySQL)
>
> Y years of experience with web development using HTML and Javascript (using jQuery and Google Web Toolkit)
>
> Proficiency with C++ and the Microsoft .NET framework.
>
> Familiar with common network protocols and practices like TCP/IP, SOAP, REST and SOA.

Comment: Yeah but this grouping sometimes becomes tricky. They can always ask on interview how well i know smth. Plus on my experience i have mentioned which technology i used with which project- this should give them idea how well i know smth

Comment: @user400500 *"They can always ask on interview how well i know smth"* <- this assumes you get an invite to an interview in the first place. Usually most applications are sorted out beforehand.

Comment: fair enough philipp, but before when I had all this stuff categorized still I hadn't mentioned how well I knew smth. So now I am just comparing if grouping vs this is good or not. listing how well you know smth is separate issue I guess. That I am mentioning in projects, listing which tool I used in which project

Comment: @user400500 Personally I tend to group things as Junior, medior and senior. I also have a similar list as I left school, However I make sure to mention that everything in my list is at junior level. If I wish to highlight some of these skills, I do so as I write my job experience and education.

Comment: Adding more information is good, but in this list the technologies are no longer highlighted for quick scanning.  I would do something like "**Java** (5 years experience)" as a heading with other Java technologies under that and each technology in bold.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that a lot over the last 30 years. Personally, I understand it but it doesn't give a whole lot of useful information. All I've done with the information is sometimes inquire as to the depth of their experience in certain areas listed.  I also have picked out some technologies and inquired so they can be a BS detector.

In other words, are you putting this there to have a list of technologies you've touched, or is it something with which you have actual expertise?

Comment: some of them one can have significant experience. But if item is there at least I have some experience with it

Answer (score 0):

If you think you can answer basic questions then yes.  They will search on language, framework, and tools.

But I would separate it out into primary and additional (or a better word). They can expect you to hit the ground running with primary skills and you should be able to answer advanced questions.  On additional you have experience but it would take you a few days to come back up to speed.

Visual Studio .Net has not been a name since like 2003.  You don't list C#.  To me that looks like dated .NET skills.  If you are going to list them then be accurate and consistent.  My BS meter would be going off.

Comment: this is just sample, not skills I have :) just example. Because this categorization may become tricky and it is questionable whether it is worth it

Comment: "If you think you can answer basic questions then yes." Yes if item is there it means I can answer basic questions